# What regex matches string within wordbounds, but not next to '@'

Tags: regex

I want to find the number of occurrences of a certain string in a text. The string can match the beginning of a sentence or at the end before the '.'. So I thought of:

```
\bMY_STRING\b
```

However, i do not want to match *parts* of an email address. That is, the string should not be next to the @ (at-sign, at-symbol, ampersat, apetail, arroba, atmark, at symbol, commercial at, monkey tail *or whatever term makes it easier to find this using a search engine*).

So, 'example' should not be counted in 'test@example.com'.

**What should replace the \b in my expression to match wordbreaks, except at @?**

Comment: What language? The regex notation varies a bit from language to language.

Comment: `&` is the `ampersand`, not `@`. Please don't confuse the Googles.

Comment: I'm going to use the expression in a Java program. Wasn't included because I hoped a generic regex solution would exist.

Comment: it spells `ampers`*`at`*, comes from wikipedia.

Comment: @Stim: Cool, never heard of it before. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your regex flavors knows lookbehind assertions (most do, but JavaScript and Ruby 1.8 only support lookahead), you can replace all `\b`s with this:

```
(?<!@)\b(?!@)
```

This matches a word boundary only if it's not before or after a `@`.

Comment: Thanks! For my specific case I will split the expression  `(?<!@)\bMY_STRING\b(?!@)`, but you got me there ;)

Comment: JavaScript has supported lookbehind assertions since ECMAScript 2018.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the lookbehind and lookahead options in regex:

```
#\b(?<![@])YOUR_TEXT(?![@])\b)#
```

[Example](http://xrg.es/?1806717336)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[^\@]
```

which means: match any character except @

Comment: But it wouldn't match the beginning or end of the text, like `^MY_STRING` or `MY_STRING$`